# Discord bot not playing local files

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a bot for a Discord server, and it will play some audio files in a voice channel. It enters the channel, but it doesn't play any sound. The terminal doesn't receive any errors and I don't know how to resolve this problem. Does anybody know what's happening?

[image: My intents]
[image: My package.json]

My code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, ChannelType, VoiceChannel } = require('discord.js');
const { joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource, AudioPlayerStatus, getVoiceConnection } = require("@discordjs/voice");
const { join } = require('path');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('voz')
        .setDescription('Reproduzo um audio na sua call discord.')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName("audio").setDescription("Escolha o audio.").addChoices( { name: "Ratinho", value: "Ratinho"}, {name: "Gira aspas", value: "Gira aspas"} ) )
        .addChannelOption(option =>
            //Ele ja busca todos os canais de voz do server
            option.setName('channel').setDescription('The channel to echo into').addChannelTypes(ChannelType.GuildVoice)),
        
    async execute(interaction) {

        const channel_voice = interaction.options.getChannel("channel"); //Puxando do interaction apenas a opcao channel.
        const audio = interaction.options.get("audio");
        
        //Entrando no canal de voz
        const voiceConnection = joinVoiceChannel({
            
            channelId: channel_voice.id, //id da canal de voz
            guildId: interaction.guildId, //id do server
            adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
            selfDeaf: false
        })

        const player = createAudioPlayer();
        //message.guild.me.voice.setRequestToSpeak(true);
        const resource = createAudioResource(join("..", "sounds", 'ratinho.ogg'));
        player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Playing, () => {

            console.log("player.on = Audio tocando");
        })
        player.on("error", error => {

            console.error(`ERRO! ${error.message}`)
        })
        voiceConnection.subscribe(player);
        player.play(resource);

        console.log(`O bot entrou no canal de voz ${channel_voice.name}.`)
        await interaction.reply(`Tocando ${audio.value}`);
    }
};
```